MySQL identifier case sensitivify and INFORMATION_SCHEMA
I have a task: pump data from a mysql database into a postgresql database. I already have a program that I use for such tasks, but it fails. The reason for this is that the MySQL database contains tables with the same name, only letter cases are different. For example, these two tables are different:

select * from `Adatlap`
select * from `adatlap`


My program queries database structure from information_schema, but in this case it fails. For example, constraints and columns appear in information_schema with all lower case identifiers:
                SELECT t.constraint_type, t.table_schema, t.table_name, k.column_name
                FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
                JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
                USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
                WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND t.table_schema='main'
                  AND t.table_name='adatlap'   

Results in:
constraint_type|table_schema  |table_name|column_name|
---------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
PRIMARY KEY    |main          |adatlap   |id         |
PRIMARY KEY    |main          |adatlap   |id         |

How can I select the contraints and the column names? Is there a different system catalog that can be used for this? Something that is case sensitive?

You can set the case sensitivity by setting lower_case_table_names. You can set it by connection (EDIT: not longer sure) or globally. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for details.
Check the current state with
mysql -e 'show variables like "lower_case_table_names"'

You can change the default value in /etc/..., sometimes /etc/my.cnf, sometimes /etc/mysql/... (depends on operating system).

I'm not able to change the server setting. But somehow dbeaver can discover constraints and columns for tables, so I guess there is a way to do it.

So I guess there is a database connection parameter that corresponds to --lower-case-table-names mysql option?
